# Calculate integer sort index column from column consisting of numbers and alphanumeric values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with the following data, where I need to calculate a sort index (integer) for each row in TSQL

| type | code |
| --- | --- |
| Fruit | 030 |
| Fruit | 040 |
| Fruit | Banana |
| Fruit | Apple 1 |
| Fruit | Apple 2 |
| Soda | 050 |
| Soda | 1 |
| Soda | 054 |
| Soda | Sprite |
| Soda | Fanta |

The sort_index column below should be calculated by type (starting from 1 for each type) and code where parsable integer codes always takes precedence over alphanumeric codes:

| type | code | sort_index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fruit | 030 | 1 |
| Fruit | 040 | 2 |
| Fruit | Apple 1 | 3 |
| Fruit | Apple 2 | 4 |
| Fruit | Banana | 5 |
| Soda | 1 | 1 |
| Soda | 050 | 2 |
| Soda | 054 | 3 |
| Soda | Fanta | 4 |
| Soda | Sprite | 5 |

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The data/rules are too messy.  You should define the `sort_index` before you import your data into SQL Server.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really able to do this. I've found the answer just after I posted this question. You can view it under - Perhaps it will make the question make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find the answer I searched for.

Use row_number() to generate an integer row number based on criterias.

Partition by resets row number per type.

Order the row number by parsable values. For values that are not parsable, we use the highest integer value, making sure that they will always be higher than the highest parsable value. Lastly sort by code to have non parsable values sorted by alphabetically.

```sql
SELECT
[type],
[code],
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [type] ORDER BY CASE WHEN try_parse(code AS INT) IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(code AS INT) ELSE 2147483647 END, code) AS [sort_index]
FROM
dbo.test_table
```

Comment: Better answers offer some explanation rather than just a bit'o'code that addresses the issue at hand. That said, the OP ought to [accept and/or upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY code Order by type) as sort_index
```

Comment: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0TIsCR1K) says that isn't quite what the OP requested.